# How to track strokeEnd point of a CAShapeLayer?

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

My question concerns the possibility of tracking the coordinates of the `strokeEnd` point of a `CAShapeLayer`.

[image: Image Of Curve Graph]

Comment: (´・ω・｀)(´・ω・｀)(´・ω・｀)(´・ω・｀)

Comment: help...(´・ω・｀)(´・ω・｀)